# Mljar python wrapper api "no such file or directory" error

Tags: python, mljar

I'm getting `Ups, [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error when I try to fit models using the python wrapper for the mljar api.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

The code:

```
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5)

from mljar import Mljar

models = Mljar(
    project='MLJAR api test', experiment='Iris',
    metric='logloss',
    validation_kfolds=5, # we will use 5-fold CV with stratify and shuffle
    validation_shuffle=True,
    validation_stratify=True,
    algorithms=['xgb', 'lgb', 'mlp'], # select Xgboost, LightGBM and Neural Network
    tuning_mode='Normal', # number of models to be checked for each algorithm
    single_algorithm_time_limit=5
)

models.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

For some reason, there is no traceback. I just get the error:
`Ups, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /tmp/dataset-002317be.csv`

Comment: show the entire traceback.

Comment: There is also a local version of MLJAR available https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out.

This is part of the python api wrapper code at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\mljar\client\dataset.py

```
def add_new_dataset(self, data, y, title_prefix = 'dataset-'):
    [...]
    file_path = '/tmp/dataset-'+ str(uuid.uuid4())[:8]+'.csv'
    [...]
    data.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
```

It tries to create the dataset file at /tmp but the directory doesn't exist.
In my opinion, the best way to solve this is to create a tmp folder at the root of your current drive.
In my case, this is shared network drive, in which there was no /tmp folder.

I also found the part of the code responsible for the missing traceback:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\mljar\mljar.py

```
except Exception as e:
    print 'Ups, %s' % str(e)
```